# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv

Помогите исправить ошибку в использовании библиотеки opencv

Хочу выполнить:

```
import cv2

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Но выскакивает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...", line ..., in <module>
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
                 ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

Что делать?

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что там есть такой аттрибут?

Comment: поискать в сети про эту ошибку и установить нужные модули.  `opencv-contrib-python`, например.

Comment: В видосах по данной библиотеке используют данный атрибут; opencv-contrib-python устанавливал - не помогло(((

Comment: Как устанавливали куда?

Comment: попробуй учиться не по видосам, а по книгам и документации. На видосах далеко не уедешь

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, все это время библиотеки устанавливались не туда, поэтому были ошибки